# Maintain document signing progress when using JWT grant

Tags: docusignapi

Building an app where I have to generate documents for users to sign (where the users are not employees that are part of the docusign account). Based on the docs here: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/, I should be using a JWT Grant for authentication.

My question is: when any user opens up the document to start signing, is there a way to maintain the progress that the user has made while keeping embedded signing? I've seen the "Finish Later" button, but that sends an email to the user.

Answer (score 1):

The status of the signing for the specific user is maintained by DocuSign. If they go back to sign again, they'll see whatever progress they made so far. In order for you to do that, you'll have to call the same API to generate a new embedded signing URL for the same user, just the same way you did the first time. You can completely avoid having any emails sent to the user if that's what you want.

Final comment - all of this has nothing to do with JWT. You can use JWT or use Auth Code Grant and the rest is the same.